# Bluemix: Mobile first on IBM Container

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, containers, ibm-cloud

I am migrating my mobile first server into IBM Container on bluemix and I have requested One public IP Address for my container .

I just want to know **public IP address which is generated by container is static or Dynamic ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a paid account, the public ips requested via `cf ic ip request`, and bound via `cf ic ip bind` are dynamic at request time, then static to your space once requested (you can see them in `cf ic ip list`).  Unbinding it will remove it from the container, but still leave it in the space to be rebound to another container (for example, the next version of the same container).

If you release it ('cf ic ip release'), then it is returned to the open pool, and if you re-request a new public ip, it is unlikely (though possible) that you will get that same ip back.

For free trial accounts, ips which have been requested but are not currently bound to a container will be occasionally cleaned up.  This will remove them from that space, in which case it would be necessary to request a new ip for use.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response .